# What is the meaning of Immigrant Background in a job application?

Tags: job, faculty-application, norway

I am in the process of application for a job. One of the questions is about immigrant background as follows:

> Applicants who state that they have immigrant background will be
> assessed in accordance with the requirements of summoning at least one
> qualified applicant with immigrant background to the interview
> process. Immigrant background implies that you are born in another
> country than Norway or have immigrated from another country or that
> both your parents are born in another country.

Could you please help me understand what this is? Is this question for those who already live in Norway and want to apply for that job? I live outside EU.

Comment: Is this the original text, or a summary or translation of the original? For a legal document it’s unusually unclear: taken as written, a Japanese person minding their own business in Tokyo is an immigrant to Brazil (if we take Brazil as country X) by the first option given.

Comment: @gnometorule It is  complete text and original

Comment: @user40491: That is quite odd as other parts, such as the term “implies” in that sentence, are also used incorrectly (what is meant is something like “is constituted by,” the opposite of “implies”). Based on the above wording and its first option stated, you are an immigrant as long as you are not born in country X, which appears to apply to you. However, I suspect that this is not what the drafter intended to say.

Comment: @gnometorule It mayl apply to all people who are legally eligible to work in that particular country (which happens to be Norway)

Comment: @Araucaria: Yes, agreed, that is probably what they meant to say, but it’s not what the wording says. Based on what it says, my entire extended family and me are Norvegian immigrants. :) I think your answer gives the right advice considering the circumstances.

Comment: @gnometorule Yes, indeed!

Comment: _Part of_ the confusion appears to originate from a subtle mistranslation from Norwegian to English.  The original Norwegian text is [here](https://oslomet.varbi.com/no/apply/positionquick/346493/?where=4), and it looks like the "or" after "COUNTRY X" should read "and".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is part of the guidance for applicants for [a specific job at Oslo Metropolitan University](https://oslomet.varbi.com/en/apply/positionquick/346493/?where=4).

This particular paragraph is, it seems, intended to encourage applicants who have some non-Norwegian heritage to apply. The original text reads:

> ... Immigrant background implies that you are born in another country than Norway or have immigrated from another country or that both your parents are born in another country.

If the Original Poster currently resides outside of Norway and was also born outside Norway, then they would seem to automatically qualify as having an immigrant background according to the information given.

By stating that at least one such applicant will always make it through to the interview stage, the University is actively encouraging eligible applicants to indicate their 'immigrant background' status on the form, although as can be seen on the original page, this is entirely optional.

If I were the Original Poster and wished to apply for this job, then I would indicate my so-called immigrant background on the form in good faith in accordance with the guidance.

[And were I called to interview and later it turned out that the guidance had not been explicit enough—and anybody cared—I would not expect the University to hold me responsible for the original miscommunication.]

Comment: The [job description](https://oslomet.varbi.com/en/what:job/jobID:346493/type:job/where:4/apply:1) for that role says 'Vi søker etter studenter som kan jobbe for oss deltid', suggesting that they're looking for applicants who are already studying at an institution in the Oslo area, in which case the 'currently resides outside of Norway' situation isn't really applicable.

Comment: However, I notice that the equivalent web form for other jobs at Oslo Metropolitan University is behind a password-requiring login screen, so it's possible that OP is talking about a different job entirely, and we just don't see the same text as applied to those jobs on the public internet.

Comment: @DanielHatton Good points